# How to hide Angular DatePicker date format prompt?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-ui-angular2

How to hide default date format description in KendoUi Angular DatePicker: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-formats

In example, usual datepicker code is like:

```
<kendo-datepicker [value]="value"></kendo-datepicker>
```

and when "value" is null or empty it shows you a prompt:

```
month/day/year
```

How to hide that prompt?

EDIT: This functionality is being in development. It should be realesed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest changes in the DateInput (as of v1.4.0-dev) two additional properties were added:

- `placeholder` - display text hint (related [Github issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/911))
- `formatPlaceholder` - control description of the format sections ([Github issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/859))

With those available, we can easily hide or modify the displayed format description:

```
<kendo-datepicker [placeholder]="Enter date..." [formatPlaceholder]="short" />
```

Here is a plunker demo that demonstrates those new properties:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XYmwDjkpp7Mb4txlmc2L?p=preview

Note, that the described functionality is available only in the **@dev** channel. **It should be released soon though.**

EDIT: `@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@1.4.0` is officially released. Just use 1.4.0 or above to utilize some of the mentioned options.

Comment: I have run yourt plunker on chrome and shows nothing on preview :(

Comment: This is strange. It seems to work on my end - https://screencast.com/t/244mTlyVr . Another option is to just build a simple Angular app using the `@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@dev` package.

Comment: I found the issue - the plunker used intranet link. The demo is updated and should work as expected. – George K 4 hours ago

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. placeholder=" "  is almost what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `kendo datepicker` place holder property.

The DateInput and DatePicker components expose a placeholder property incorrectly. By default, the date format string, e.g. month/day/year, is displayed.

You can get  more details on [**#519**](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/519).

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no way to do this programmatically, however I have an idea of how to do that and I briefly tested it in Chrome Dev Tools.

Put some class on your datepicker component

`<kendo-datepicker [ngClass]={'empty': !date }>`

Then add styles

```
.k-datepicker.empty input {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

That should do the trick.